# How to prevent the last one checked checkbox from unchecking in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox

I have a problem with angular 2, I don't know how to check back the last checkbox after unchecking. 
Here is my piece of HTML:

```
<td *ngFor="let box of checkedBoxes"><input
    type="checkbox"
    value="{{box.name}}"
    id="{{box.name}}"
    [(ngModel)]="box.checked"
    (ngModelChange)="updateGroupByCheckboxes($event, box.name)">
    <label>{{box.label}}</label>
</td>
```

And here my .ts code:

```
checkedBoxes: any[] = [{
    "name": "box1",
    "label": "Box1",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "name": "box2",
    "label": "Box2",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "name": "box3",
    "label": "Box3",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "name": "box4",
    "label": "Box4",
    "checked": false
  }];
```

And:

```
updateGroupByCheckboxes(event, name) {

    var counter = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.checkedBoxes.length && counter <= 1; i++) {
      if(counter > 1) {
        break;
      }

      if(this.checkedBoxes[i].checked) {
        counter++;
      }
    }

    if(counter < 1 && event == false) {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
        if(this.checkedBoxes[i].name == name) {
          console.log("val: " + this.checkedBoxes[i].checked);
          this.checkedBoxes[i].checked = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      this.checkedBoxes[3].checked = !this.checkedBoxes[3].checked;
      var grouppingData = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < this.checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
        if(this.checkedBoxes[i].checked == true){
          grouppingData.push(this.checkedBoxes[i].name);
        }
      }
      this.statistics = this.statisticsService.getStatistics(grouppingData);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this line: `this.checkedBoxes[i].checked = true;` doesn't work in my case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" checked readonly />`?

Comment: use #last `*ng-for="#item of list; #i = index; #last = last"` readonly if last

Comment: readonly doesn't work as I want it to. I can still tick/untick checkboxes